# Maintaining unique entries in PROMPT_COMMAND

Tags: bash

There is only one `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which runs just before showing the prompt. To add commands to be run a typical method is:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="my_command; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

The problem is this line adds `my_command` even if its already been added. I quite like to source my `~/.bashrc` after updating it and not have things break or execute redundantly. With the above in `.bashrc`, `PROMPT_COMMAND` expands to `mycommand; mycommand; mycommand; mycommand; ...`

One idea I had was to split based on `;` and recombine:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=$( echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND" | sed 's/^ *\(.*[^ ]\) *$/\1/' | sed 's/ *; */\n/g' | sed '/^$/d' | sort -u | tr '\n' ';' )
```

However some commands include `;` inside strings and subshell commands, which breaks the above as quotes, brackets and escape characters are ignored. How can I cleanly maintain multiple `PROMPT_COMMAND`s?

Answer (score 0):

This function appends somethig to `PROMPT_COMMAND` only if it's not already there.

```
function prompt_command_push() {
    if [[ "$PROMPT_COMMAND" != *"$@"* ]]; then
        if [[ -n "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]]; then
            export PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND;$@"
        else
            export PROMPT_COMMAND="$@"
        fi
    fi
}

prompt_command_push printf hello
prompt_command_push echo '\ world'
```

Care should be taken with "$@" usage as strings and escape sequences get parsed twice.

This function appends, rather than prepends commands so the most recent addition is executed last.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach this problem is to create a *new* variable to retain a copy of the *original* `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

Put this in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export ORIGINAL_PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
export PROMPT_COMMAND="my_command; ${ORIGINAL_PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

This will cause your `my_command` to only be executed once and the original `PROMPT_COMMAND` will be respected.